# Best React Router login practise

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router

What is the best Reactjs Router login practise that allows checking login status before rendering and rerendering if it changes

i tried using useState and useEffect and passing loggedIn (status) as props but it render before setting state so i have to refresh page to get update

```
        function App() {
      Axios.defaults.withCredentials=true
      const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)

      useEffect(()=>{
        checkLoginStatus()
      },[loggedIn])

function checkLoginStatus(){
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/loggedin')
    .then(res =>{
      if(res.data.Loggedin){
        if(!loggedIn){
        setLoggedIn(true)
        }
      }else{
        setLoggedIn(false)
      }
    }
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  return (
    <Router>
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/'  render={props => (<Home {...props} loggedIn={loggedIn}  />)}/>
         <Route path='/login' render={props => <LoginForm {...props} loggedIn={loggedIn} />} />
         <Route path='/register' component={RegisterForm} />
         <Route path='/logout' component={Logout} />
       </Switch>
       </Router>
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is: do you set the `loggedIn` state somewhere outside your `checkLoginStatus()`?

If not - you have a vicious circle here: you check and change the `loggedIn` only when the `loggedIn` changes...

Change your `useEffect()` dependency to `[]` to make it a `componentDidMount()` hook, I think that's what you want.

**edit**
About that initial render: it's obvious that initially it doesn't render as logged in. You send a request to server and have to await the results, it's an async function of course. You have two choices here: render a loading component while waiting for response or make an optimistic asumption that a user is logged-in and if a response says that he's not - log him out.